# How would you plot co-ordinates on a grid made from equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

The standard square grid has two axis: x and y, how would a grid made from tesselating equilateral triangles work? (An isometric grid) Triangles don't have 2 sets of parrallel sides, like squares so as far as I can tell 3 axis are needed:
[Isometric Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnD9M.png)

But then there is no easy way of interpreting it as each axis must have its respective grid lines coming of it from either a 30' angle or a 60' angle. And you have the problem where not all coordinate combinations can actually lie on the grid, eg. (x:1, y:2, z:3).

Is there some pre-existing method/standard of plotting "isometric coordinates" or is there no other way?

Ps. Sorry if the tags are wrong

Comment: Ah, oops now I feel dumb

Comment: This is a projection of a 3d coordinate system to 2d.  Start from there.